# Grails exception handling in URLMappings.groovy for AJAX error

Tags: ajax, grails, exception

I have a Grails application that makes HTTP requests to a back end server for it's data. That server can be taken down for maintenance, and when that happens it will return a "site down" message to the Grails app in the HTTP response. The Grails app is detecting this and throws a custom SiteDownException. In URLMappings.groovy this is then directed to a specific error page.

This works well apart from for AJAX requests. What seems to happen is that the "site down" URL mapping is triggered (as expected) followed by the catch all '500' mapping.

URLMappings.groovy

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "siteDown", exception: SiteDownException)
"500"(controller: "error", action: "error500")
```

ErrorController.groovy

```
def siteDown() {
println ">>>> site down <<<<"
}

def error500() {
println ">>>> 500 <<<<"
}
```

The error is thrown using

```
throw new SiteDownException()
```

For regular requests the stacktrace shows...

```
[11/11/13 16:52:50.945 error] SiteDownException occurred when processing request: [POST] /portal/contact/detail - parameters:
fileKeyIdentifier: 
mode: add
Stacktrace follows: [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  http-bio-8080-exec-6]
com.ui.exceptions.SiteDownException
    at com.ui.backend.Backend$$EOMu30qx.getResponse(Backend.groovy:118)
    at com.ui.backend.Backend$$EOMu30qx.getResponseAsDomainObject(Backend.groovy:41)
    at com.ui.contact.ContactService.detail(ContactService.groovy:166)
    at com.ui.contact.ContactController.detail(ContactController.groovy:87)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>>>> site down <<<<
```

Spot on, but for AJAX requests...

```
    [11/11/13 16:54:09.380 error] SiteDownException occurred when processing request: [POST] /portal/contact/searchBody
Stacktrace follows: [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  http-bio-8080-exec-7]
com.ui.exceptions.SiteDownException
    at com.ui.backend.Backend$$EOMu30qx.getResponse(Backend.groovy:118)
    at com.ui.backend.Backend$$EOMu30qx.getResponseAsDomainObject(Backend.groovy:41)
    at com.ui.contact.ContactService.searchBody(ContactService.groovy:55)
    at com.ui.contact.ContactController.searchBody(ContactController.groovy:23)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>>>> site down <<<<
>>>> 500 <<<<
```

The last bit is key - it displays the "site down" message from the siteDown action, and "500" from the catch all error500 action.

Can anyone help explain why are both mappings being called for AJAX errors? Thanks

Comment: After further thought i decided to just map the SiteDownException to my 500 error page and pick up the Exception.cause to decide what content to show, however this still doesn't work. For AJAX errors the 500 mapping is called twice, the first time the correct Exception is passed but the second time the Exception is null so still no use to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I had an error trap in the jQuery AJAX wrapper:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
     window.location.href = config.contextPath + '/error/error500'; // Error - show the 500 error page
}
```

So the SiteDownException was correctly firing the SiteDown mapping, then the AJAX error handler was firing error500 mapping.